# Getting Latest Version for all files in a Project

Tags: eclipse, tfs

Is there a way to get the latest version for all files in a project from tfs? I'm wondering if eclipse has an easy one-click solution somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

TFS offers a Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse, as part of the Team Explorer Everywhere tools.

You can simply download the TFS plug-in for Eclipse from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785

After that, you can right-click on the project itself in Package Explorer, and select "Get Latest Version" to get the entire project (recursively).  You can even multi-select several projects to get the latest version in *all* those projects.

Comment: Yep I got it. Instead of right clicking all my files individually and getting the latest verison, is there a way to just specify all?

Comment: Sure, just select the project itself in Package Explorer.  (Note that some Eclipse views do not show the Team menu contributions, so make sure that you're in Package Explorer!)